# Regex in express route handler overriding default route

Tags: regex, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var tracker = require('../lib/pixel-track')
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'index' });
});

router.get(/^\/(([0-9a-zA-Z\._-])+.(gif|GIF))$/, tracker.requestHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

So I have this express router.  According to my logic, that second statement matches any request to a ` /whatever.gif, and the first one is just for /.  For some reason, requests at / still send the gif.  I'm a little confused as to how the regex route handler took over my index route handler.

Interestingly I have the exact same regex route and tracker code at a /api location, and it works fine, not overriding the index.  Also, if I comment out the router.get('/' ... route, it still presents the pixel at localhost:4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it without using the Router module directly. Not sure what you're aiming at with using it that way?

You also don't need such a complicated regex:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/* GET home page. */
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("got /");
    res.end("/");
});

app.get(/^\/[\w-.]+\.gif$/i, function(req, res) {
    console.log("got gif");
    res.end("a gif!");
});

app.listen(8000);
```

**Update**

Best I can tell, reason it's not handling your original route in your code, is because in your repo, the `api` var (path to the index file) is `var api = require('./routes/api/index');` whereas your index is set in `indexRoute` and you're not using that anywhere. Remember that in routes, the path defined in `app.use` is treated as the base-path, so:

Assuming you had this in your app.js:

```
var indexRoute = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api/index');
app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.use('/api', api);
```

And these route handlers:

```
// /routes/api/index.js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('You called api route /');
});

// /routes/index.js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('You called index route /');
});
router.get(/^\/[\w-.]+\.gif$/i, function(req, res) {
    res.end("a gif!");
});
```

This seems to work for me (albeit `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` was blocking the `/` route!).

Comment: I moved it into the router because I originally had it in the app after the router app.use('/'... statement. I was wondering if the transfer to the router would change it.  Also, that was the first regex I ever wrote haha, and I need to get a piece of info out of the gif request so I needed some ((('s.  But would the complexity of the regex mess with the route?  I'm not sure this answers it.  That router is just one file of the app.  I'm just confused as to why this route is over-riding my default one that appears before it no less.  I'm wondering why the / request doesnt serve the index.

Comment: I will follow up when I get home today and try out that.  I also tried it outside of the route with an app.get(... like you showed, so I don't think simply switching it to an app instance from a router instance will fix it.  Could this be an actual bug?

PS : https://github.com/dkran/pixel is the code

Comment: missing dependencies and breaking bug? I updated to the new version of express, still won't load / route when requested.  I'm trying this on both ubuntu and osx with nodemon.  All it does is load pixels on / or /anything.gif, I can't get the index to render..  I guess I'll dig further.  I dunno why it works for you and not myself.

Comment: oh, well I didn't put my npm packages in the repo.

Comment: but my point in the beginning was if I go to /whatever.gif, it loads a pixel.  idk why yours had an error, but if I go to /, it SHOULD res.render(index, {title: index});, BUT INSTEAD it gives me a pixel.  Is that not apparent from my first post?

Comment: OK see edits -- lots of guesswork, but I have it at least working locally now.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, My local code actually had the indexRoute implemented, but in tinkering with things, github gets out of sync.  

I think the more grandiose question here is why is express.static blocking my index route? lol

NOTE: If you notice, browsing to /api/r does not load a pixel, but if it were acting consistent with the same regex at /, it would.  *scratches head*

Comment: Well, I found the answer.  The answer is express static has to go at the bottom, otherwise it's interfering with the index route.